# Paypal Recurring_payment_failed and Recurring_payment_cancel txn_types

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I was going through the Paypal documentation and wanted to make sure, do paypal does not support the transaction types:
Recurring_payment_failed and Recurring_payment_cancel

Answer (score 1):

There is a `txn_type` of `recurring_payment_profile_cancel` and `recurring_payment_failed`. If you're using the Recurring Payment API calls you would see those values returned to you.

If you're using custom created Subscription buttons you would get back the `subscr` values.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am using Recurring Payment Api. The reason i asked that is because there is no `txn_type` `recurring_payment_profile_cancel` and `recurring_payment_failed` in the Paypal Recurring API Documentation. So are you sure Paypal still supports these `txn_type`?

Comment: You wouldn't find them in the Recurring Payment documentation. They're IPN variables. You would find them in the IPN documentation.

Comment: (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/). In IPN Documentation too there are just 4 Recurring API `txn_type`, `recurring_payment`, `recurring_payment_expired`, `recurring_payment_profile_created` and `recurring_payment_skipped` but not `recurring_payment_profile_cancel` and `recurring_payment_failed`

Comment: Although the comment above is correct, as the docs page says, these are for transactions. I am currently testing and can confirm that recurring_payment_profile_cancel exists, but I have not been able to test the failed status

Comment: That IPN document doesn't cover everything. There isn't a count of the REST IPN variables either. I'll submit a Feature Request to include the extra Recurring Payment information but it may be awhile longer before the REST stuff gets added.